# How to match a single column id with a multiple id in a single cloumn

Tags: mysql, database

i have two tables namely test and questionentry. questionentry table is having qId(int), questionName and subject field(Column) and on the other hand, test table contains testId, duration, questionIds(Var char) and publish etc. In testId, i have multiple values of qId stored in it in format eg 22,23,24,25,28. I am having a problem about how to select only the particular rows in which questionentry.qId exist in test.questionIds. Since i am using questionName in varchar format so it's difficult for me to compare it. Any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: So, if you are having problems because you stored numbers delimited by a comma in a single column - don't you think you'd have easier time if you had `questionId` as integer and then multiple rows representing each question for a single test? Bottom line is - your database scheme is wrong. You need to fix it.

Comment: I also thought the same thing but the problem is i am making an online test panel in which in a single test you can add any number of questions by clicking an add button which will open list of question and then add all of them in just one click so which will produce problem as there will be many number of rows to insert, delete and update.

Comment: *"which will produce problem as there will be many number of rows to insert, delete and update"* - what problems?

Comment: Lets say if i am inserting testId in the question table and which has selected from the admin panel then i will have to insert the current test id to the selected question and also mannually i will have to create a new column for every new test?

Comment: Your tables are poorly designed you should have a separate tables to store the additional information for `testId`

Comment: A test consists of multiple questions. If every question is represented by a row in the `tests` table, then what problems exactly do you have? Databases are *made* for this purpose. If you have a test with 1000 questions, then you create 1000 rows. Problem solved, you never have to look back.

Comment: Then my query will be long for eg writnig an update query and insert query from question 1 to question 1000.if there is any solution for my prblem then it will save lots of time and lines of code

Comment: But you will have an update, delete and insert anomally. for example what if i want to change one or more questions in your test table. It would be very difficult query wise and your PL of choice had to do a lot of extras in order to achieve a supposedly easy and straightforward task.

Comment: If you are talking about my pl side then you in each test, there is an option of adding question by selecting it and after that i will store it in an array and then put implode function it by inserting a commas and after that i can easily update or insert it in my particular rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program-related problem looks like a result of poor database design and more specifically a violation of 1st normal form in normalizing tables like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

It is more advisable to normalize your table first then you will have relatively easy time in creating your queries and your code of choice.

You could probably have like this:

**Test** table : Testid, duration

**QuestionEntry** table qID, QuestionName, Subject

**QuestionTest** Table : qID, TestID

Comment: LEts take an example, if a question occurs more than one test then? For more clear view, if question 1 is a part of test1, test2, test3 and test 10 then? I will always have to be inserting into a ne wcolumn

Comment: In a many to many relationship that could be easily achieved by adding an extra table as a link. So, the question doesn't have to be inserted all the time except its primary key.

Comment: you means by creating  table name testQuestion and in that table i will add three fields id, testId and questionId. If that's what you are talking about then i will have to do loop in my query for eg. if a user has selected 15 questions then i will have to insert all 15 question in a new row. am i right?

Comment: You may loop 15 times in your PL of choice but you will have only one insert command to fire. In your design by the way you have to loop still 15 times in your PL of choice checking which one was chosen by the user before updating supposedly one column. Yet you will have extremely difficult later on when you want do some queries like counts for example whereas the normalized table would be relatively easy.

Comment: Hmmm, so according to you what shall be the best way in order to do it. Like test table, there is also a package table too which contains multiple test ids inside of a one column.It's been my very first time to doing something like that. :(

Comment: Have you look at my update in my answer which i have 3 tables? There is no multiple ID in one column because that's multivalued column which is a violayion of 1st normal form.

Comment: Yup, i looked at that. I think it's also been the nice way too. It's called a many to many relationship. I am accepting your answer. Thanks a lot for your time on me.

Comment: My pleasure @GotBanned. I hope to see more of you here. GOD bless.

Comment: Mine pleasure too also :)))